# Arduino Compiling Error

Tags: programming

I recently format my  Windows 8 and installed Windows 8.1 . In Windows 8, I was using Arduino IDE and there was no error in compiling.But then I installed Windows 8.1 and re-installed Arduino IDE.I tried various codes for motor drivers and everything but they didn't compile.So, I tried to compile blink LED example first and even it didn't compile.It shows the following error on UPLOADING BLINK LED Example-

```
Arduino: 1.8.2 (Windows 8.1), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

C:\Program Files\Arduino\arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware -tools C:\Program Files\Arduino\tools-builder -tools C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -built-in-libraries C:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries -libraries C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Arduino\libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:uno -vid-pid=0X2341_0X0043 -ide-version=10802 -build-path C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_754363 -warnings=none -build-cache C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_657645 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -verbose C:\Program Files\Arduino\examples\01.Basics\Blink\Blink.ino
C:\Program Files\Arduino\arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware -tools C:\Program Files\Arduino\tools-builder -tools C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -built-in-libraries C:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries -libraries C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Arduino\libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:uno -vid-pid=0X2341_0X0043 -ide-version=10802 -build-path C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_754363 -warnings=none -build-cache C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_657645 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -verbose C:\Program Files\Arduino\examples\01.Basics\Blink\Blink.ino
Using board 'uno' from platform in folder: C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr
Using core 'arduino' from platform in folder: C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr
Detecting libraries used...
"C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics  -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10802 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_754363\sketch\Blink.ino.cpp" -o "nul"
Generating function prototypes...
"C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics  -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10802 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_754363\sketch\Blink.ino.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_754363\preproc\ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"
"C:\Program Files\Arduino\tools-builder\ctags\5.8-arduino11/ctags" -u --language-force=c++ -f - --c++-kinds=svpf --fields=KSTtzns --line-directives "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_754363\preproc\ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.
```

I tried RE-installing the software and drivers.It didn't work

Why is this happening?What is the Solution?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the Arduino icon, select properties. Under the compatibility tab, check "Run this program in compatibility mode" and select Windows XP. You might also want to run it as administrator.

This should hopefully solve the issue.

[Source](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=179586)

Comment: I suspect also installing the IDE as a user rather than admin and running it as that user will also fix the problem. (But I have no evidence of that)

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Arduino. Then find the Arduino folder in your Appdata folder and delete it. Then reinstall Arduino. This is happening because after a library import, there might have been a clash in the Appdata and since uninstalling doesn't delete Appdata, just reinstalling wouldn't help. This happened to me when a PPM and Servo library clashed!

Note: Do this only after you try uploading a blank sketch and it still fails! Also be careful while in the Appdata folder.